# A question on triangle identities

Tags: monoidal-categories, ct.category-theory

It is well known that pentagon+triangle identity of type (a1b) implies "all diagrams commute" [monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), in particular triangle identities of type (1ab) and (ab1). My question is that whether pentagon+triangle identity of type (1ab), or (ab1), implies triangle identity of type (a1b)?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I do not know what you men by ... of type (...). (Pentagon + triangle identity of type (a1b) for instance).

Comment: By triangle identity of type(a1b), I mean the identity (a1)b-->a(1b)-->ab == (a1)b-->b.

Comment: sorry, there is a typo. (a1)b-->a(1b)-->ab == (a1)b-->ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: No for monoidal categories, but Yes for symmetric monoidal categories. Actually, you can get away with a lot less for the Yes. Intuitively, all you need is for the unit to commute with arbitrary elements, i.e. $\rho_x = \lambda_x \circ \tau: x\otimes 1 \rightarrow x$.

The No is a result of the observation that if you only have the triangle identity of type (1ab) then you only have diagrams involving $\lambda$ and $\alpha$, which means you have no hope of getting the diagrams involving $\rho$ to commute. For the readers who don't want to dig through the nLab article, a diagram of type (1ab) means:

$\begin{array}{ccc} 1\otimes (a\otimes b) & \rightarrow & (1\otimes a)\otimes b\\\
\\\
\lambda_{a\otimes b}\downarrow  & & \downarrow \lambda_{a} \otimes 1_b\\\
\\\
a\otimes b & = & a\otimes b\\\
\end{array}$

The associative pentagon only deals with $\alpha$, and without some kind of twist map there is no way to relate $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ with $\rho$. Thus, I don't think the diagram of type (a1b) will commute, since the left vertical map in that diagram will be $\rho_a \otimes 1_b:(a\otimes 1)\otimes b \rightarrow a\otimes b$

Now, to get the Yes we require the following to commute:

$\begin{array}{ccc} x\otimes 1 & \rightarrow^\tau & 1\otimes x\\\
\\\
\lambda_{x}\downarrow  & & \downarrow \rho_{x}\\\
\\\
x & = & x\\\
\end{array}$

From this it is clear how to relate $\rho$ and $\tau$. I verified that (a1b) holds by drawing a diagram with $a\otimes b$ in the center and with the outside a bunch of triangles which all commuted except one (and therefore the last must commute). Here's a list of the vertices of the triangles I used. I'll leave the diagram chase to you (mostly because it would be a nightmare to tex in this environment): $a(1b), a(b1), (ab)1, 1(ab), (1a)b, (a1)b$. There could very well be an easier proof.